# accessing array within multidimensional array - javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

here is the problem

```
multiDimensionalArray = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9, [10, 11, 12, [13, 14, [15]]]]]];
```

I want to access number 15. I cant seem to figure it out.

p.s i am a newbee with js

Comment: `multiDimensionalArray.flat().pop()`

Comment: extension of what @JonasWilms suggested `multiDimensionalArray.flat(Infinity).pop()`, default depth is just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiDimensionalArray[3][3][3][3][2][0]`

Each `[n]` is accessing an array value at index `n`.
So the above statement says:

1) take the 4th (index 3 is the 4th element due to indices starting at 0, not 1) element.

2) This happens to be an array. Take the 4th element again.

3) ...